# × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, axios

hey guys i don't understand why am I getting this error when i want get api from api.Covid19 and it return a object that contain Countries array whenever i want map over Countries i get this error
and if i get Countries api separately it work find :| help me pls[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9G6j.png)

[getting from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9G6j.png)

[using context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJpXR.png)

[looping over data.Countries (this is problem section)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anZvP.png)

and the image below shows what api returns :
[object return by api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ6D7.png)

Comment: please add fast your tried code before its gets deleted

Comment: The incoming response may come after the component has been rendered. You need to check if there is data in Countries at the time of rendering. For example, check `data.Countries.length > 0` before using `map`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question, _not as images_.

Comment: You've initialised your state with an empty object rather than an empty array. See if changing that makes a difference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

The initial `data` state is an object with no defined `Countries` property, so in the component `data.countries` is undefined and throws error when you attempt to map it.

The `https://api.covid19api.com/summary` endpoint does return an object with a  `Countries` property.

> ```
> / 20211121231605
> // https://api.covid19api.com/summary
>
> {
>   "ID": "03b65afe-02ad-4835-abb5-9916c44bae85",
>   "Message": "",
>   "Global": {
>     "NewConfirmed": 408370,
>     "TotalConfirmed": 256947981,
>     "NewDeaths": 5200,
>     "TotalDeaths": 5144527,
>     "NewRecovered": 0,
>     "TotalRecovered": 0,
>     "Date": "2021-11-22T06:09:08.91Z"
>   },
>   "Countries": [
>     {
>       "ID": "19a0f201-0385-42ee-bfec-cfe99666a87c",
>       "Country": "Afghanistan",
>       "CountryCode": "AF",
>       "Slug": "afghanistan",
>       "NewConfirmed": 32,
>       "TotalConfirmed": 156896,
>       "NewDeaths": 2,
>       "TotalDeaths": 7365,
>       "NewRecovered": 0,
>       "TotalRecovered": 0,
>       "Date": "2021-11-22T06:09:08.91Z",
>       "Premium": {
>         
>       }
>     },
>     ...
> ```

The solution seems to be to provide valid initial state in the provider for what you expect all consumers to render from:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ Countries: [] });
```

Or just use null/checks/guard-clauses or Optional Chaining operator to protect against the null/undefined accesses.

```
data.Countries && data.Countries.map(country => (
  <h2 key={country.ISO2}>
    {country.Country}
  </h2>
))
```

...

```
data.Countries?.map(country => (
  <h2 key={country.ISO2}>
    {country.Country}
  </h2>
))
```